# Error while retieving CLOB from Oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

The Following code attempts to retrieve a CLOB file from oracle database in JDBC.

Code:-

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Retrieving_Clob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

 DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user", "system");
    p.put("password", "password");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from  myclob");

    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    rs.next();

     Reader r = rs.getCharacterStream(1);

    int ch;

    File file = new File("H:/newFile.txt");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);

    while((ch= r.read())!= -1)
        fw.write((char)ch);

    fw.close();
    con.close();
}
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the CLOB file from the resultset index=1.The code is giving me the following error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jdbc.Retrieving_Clob.main(Retrieving_Clob.java:41)
```

The erroneous line being:-

```
        while((ch= r.read())!= -1)
```

What is the reason for the error and how to solve the problem?

**Note :-** A blank file by the provided name is getting created at the given location.

Comment: Using `select *` and then calling `ResultSet.getX(1)` is very hacky. Better to either select the specific column or get by the column name (or both).

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `r` is NULL.  You're getting `r` from:

```
Reader r = rs.getCharacterStream(1);
```

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getCharacterStream%28int%29: (getCharacterStream) returns:
    a java.io.Reader object that contains the column value; **if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null** in the Java programming language.

So it appears that the column value is NULL.

Comment: Thnks. I have observed that if I just set the Id(Integer) and then try to update the clob value through JDBC for given ID, my program shows success but Oracle shows it to be NULL. However if i update both the values together then there is no problem, evrythng wrks fyn. Any Idea Why? Using Oracle 10g Xe.

Comment: I don't understand.  Which values are you updating?

Comment: Well my table got two values (CLOB,INT) in that order.If I update only the INT from SQL commands and then i update the clob file using WHERE clause from JDBC code to match the INT value already in the table,I get the aforesaid error. But If i update both(CLOB,INT) together from JDBC then it works fine.

Comment: That sounds like it should be a separate question, since I don't see anything in your code that's doing UPDATEs.

Comment: Can u pls look at the following link, it's a different issue, regarding Blob: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513812/error-in-updating-blob-file)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for problem is obviously that fact that `r` is just `null`. Solving will be additional check for `null` in this variable:

`if (r != null) ... while...`.