# Error in updating BLOB file

Tags: java, oracle10g, blob

Code:-

```
package jdbc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Storing_Clob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user", "system");
    p.put("password", "password");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("update myclob set CLOB_VALUE=? where ID = 100");

    URL url = Storing_Clob.class.getResource("/images/clob1.txt");

    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

    pstmt.setCharacterStream(1,fr,(int)file.length());

    System.out.println("File size: "+(int)file.length());

    System.out.println("No of rows affected: "+pstmt.executeUpdate());

    con.close();

}
```

}

OutPut:- Length of string: 5395

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java)
at jdbc.Storing_Image.main(Storing_Image.java:39)
```

Erroneous Line:-

```
        System.out.println("No of rows affected: "+pstmt.executeUpdate());
```

I am trying to store a blob file(image) into the myblob table.The table has only one field - BLOB. 
Can any body please explain the reason for the error and how to solve it?
thnks in advance.

Comment: Version of Oracle and its driver?

Comment: @PopoFibo Oracle 10g xe. I have downloaded the latest driver in .jar format(ojdbc6_g.jar) from Oracle site

Answer (score 0):

Probably facing a typecasting issue try **byte** instead on **int**:

```
pstmt.setCharacterStream(1,fr,(byte)file.length());
```